# How to modify the limit minimum 5 Seconds in Cognos visualization?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

How to modify the limit minimum 5 Seconds  in  Cognos visualization  ?

5 seconds is too small. We want make it above 1 hour at least.

See the black square in the picture below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGjvY.png)

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  "above 1 hour" is not smaller than 5 seconds.  What's the real problem?

Comment: Make the users only can update the visualizations above one hours. The minimum config unit is seconds ,which is too small for our policy. We don’t want the users can choice the update frequency below one hour

Comment: I don't know if that's configurable.  That may be in the docs.  It's probably a custom property you would enter in advanced options somewhere in Cognos Administration or in an XML file.  But Cognos relies on the web browser.  Sessions tend to time out in less than an hour.  Stale sessions may cause trouble with what you're trying to do.  If you find a solution, please post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: Yes  I'll .  I see nothing about my question  in  IBM  docs, so I am Here. Thanks.

Comment: The Sessions will not be an issue. The origin design is that users can choice one hour as the update frequency for visualizations. We just force the users do it.  :)